# How to activate a function after a given time?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, nstimer

I would like to activate a function after a sound is played and complete. I assume that NSTimer needs to be included, but I am not sure of how to implement in order to make it. It is helpful if you could give me some code that works.

Comment: Have you tried googling your issue? `swift nstimer` for example gives plenty of results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should post code that you tried, and then someone then can help you make the code work.  In this case, you don't need a timer for what you're doing.  The `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` protocol on the player was designed for what you are trying to do:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

    func playSound(fileName:NSString)
    {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType:"wav")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

        do {
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
            audioPlayer?.delegate = self
            audioPlayer?.play()
        } catch {
            print("Player not available")
        }
    }

    //MARK : AVAudioPlayerDelegate
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        print("finished playing, do something else here")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I would recommend as well. The `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_, successfully:)` method is how you should invoke code when a sound finishes playing.